# Is there a way to hide the action of pyautogui.press()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyautogui

I want to automate the launching of Microsoft Store applications and I thought of using `pyautogui` and doing it in the following way.

Here `gui.press('win')` will open the windows search pop up, and then the next two lines will type `skype` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> respectively.

Is there a way in which I can hide the action of `gui.press('win')` such that when I run the script, skype launches directly?

```
import pyautogui as gui
gui.press("win")
gui.typewrite("Skype")
gui.press("enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to automate loading of programs from python why not call the OS and run the start command?

```
import os

os.system('start notepad.exe')  # this will start notepad

os.system('start C:\Apps/audacity/audacity.exe') # will start audacity as it is located in the apps folder
```

As for finding the executable there are a couple of options that can be used.

```
from distutils import spawn
spawn.find_executable('notepad')
Out[38]: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe'
```

Or

```
from shutil import which
which('notepad')
Out[55]: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.EXE'
```

Comment: @Hojo.Timerwolf,I thought about using os.system, but for that the location of the application is required and i cannot find a way to find the location of all the inbuilt microsoft applicaitons, that's why the pyautogui approach.

Comment: I just updated to incorporate some methods for finding an executable.